# sqlalchemy update one to many without selecting first

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

**Hello Dear All.**

I know how to update `One to Many` values when selecting the parent first and after that attach the many values to it. 
(here is the working version)

```py
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
some_values_ids = [1,2,....]
user = session.query(User).get(user_id)
user.some_values = session.query(SomeValue).filter(SomeValue.id.in_(some_values_ids)).all()}
```

**my question is**:
Is there a way to update without selecting the user first?
For example, is it possible to do something like that?

```py
{'some_values': session.query(SomeValue).filter(SomeValue.id.in_(some_values_ids)).all()}
session.query(User).filter(User.id == user_id).update(update)
```

The schemas are:

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    ....
    some_values = relationship(SomeValue, secondary=UserSomeValue.__tablename__)

class UserSomeValue(Base):

    __tablename__ = "user_some_value"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    some_value_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("some_value.id"), nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (Index("user_to_some_value", "user_id", "some_value_id", unique=True), )


class SomeValue(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'some_value'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(VARCHAR(length=255), nullable=False, unique=True)
```

Thank you very much
shay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with `.update`, but you can overwrite the user's collection, assuming that you know the user's `id` or have some other way to uniquely identify it in a query:

```
some_vals = session.query(SomeValue).filter(SomeValue.id.in_(some_values_ids)).all()
user = session.query(User).get(user_id).some_values = some_vals
```

or

```
some_vals = session.query(SomeValue).filter(SomeValue.id.in_(some_values_ids)).all()
user = session.query(User).filter(User.name == 'foo').one().some_values = some_vals
```

Comment: I think that the question demonstrated these methods and was trying to avoid them. It would be doable in a single query and without selecting the user first in PostgreSQL, i.e. DELETE in a CTE and INSERT the new rows to the association table.

Comment: @IljaEverilä you could well be right - the example in the question is not entirely clear, to me.  Let's see what the OP has to say.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. you are correct. my attempt is to avoid selecting first.